# Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

```
public bool location() 
{

    string OUI = "OUI";

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-218NC1F1FE2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=projet;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(id_reservation) from reservation");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    Int32 maxId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    string v = Convert.ToString(maxId);
    //correct 


    SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand("insert into reservation(location) values('" + OUI + "') where id_reservation ='"+ maxId + "'", con);
    SqlDataReader da = q.ExecuteReader();
    return true ;
}
```

the probleme was in command where : Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'where'.
help !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not have a `where` clause in an `insert` statement. That's all that is to it. If you want to insert, remove the `where` clause. If you need to update records that match a condition, don't use `insert` but `update`.

Also, if you're not really interested in the result of a query, don't use `ExecuteReader` but `ExecuteNonQuery`.

Comment: That is not true.  If the insert statement uses a Select then you can have a where clause modifying the select.

Comment: **That's something totally different**. The WHERE clause then belongs to the SELECT and **not** to the INSERT statement. You can of course have a WHERE clause in a SELECT, but you can not have a WHERE clause in an INSERT the way it is suggested in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Thorsten answer is clear an complete I am just adding the code for each case:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=WIN-218NC1F1FE2\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=projet;Integrated Security=True");
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select max(id_reservation) from reservation");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    Int32 maxId = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();  
     string ID=maxId.TOString();
    //correct 

 /////INSERT  
    SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand("insert into reservation(location) values(@location,@ID)", con);
          q.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@location",OUI);
          q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID);
          q.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
          return true ;
////////UPDATE

     SqlCommand q = new SqlCommand("update  reservation set location=@location where id_reservation =@ID", con);
              q.Parameters.AddWithValue( "@location",OUI);
              q.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID",ID);
              q.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
               return true ;
```